# How do I correctly use pd.set_option?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly wide dataframe and when I print it, it comes out truncated.

```
index  match_datetime       country    league           home_team          away_team                    home_odds    draw_odds    away_odds    predicted_home_score    predicted_away_score    predicted_btts    predicted_class_btts    predicted_bttso2.5    predicted_class_bttso2.5    predicted_bttsu2.5    predicted_class_bttsu2.5    predicted_o2.5    predicted_class_o2.5    predicted_u2.5    predicted_class_u2.5    predicted_o1.5    predicted_class_o1.5    predicted_u1.5    predicted_class_u1.5  run_time                      predicted_o4    predicted_class_o4    predicted_u4    predicted_class_u4    predicted_draw    predicted_class_draw    predicted_total_score    predicted_score_difference    Win    DNB  datetime               home_score    away_score  selection    predicted_result    result      total_score    score_difference  result_match    selection_match
-------  -------------------  ---------  ---------------  -----------------  -------------------------  -----------  -----------  -----------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  --------------------  --------------------------  --------------------  --------------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  --------------------------  --------------  --------------------  --------------  --------------------  ----------------  ----------------------  -----------------------  ----------------------------  -----  -----  -------------------  ------------  ------------  -----------  ------------------  --------  -------------  ------------------  --------------  -----------------
      0  2021-08-06 06:00:00  Russia     FNL 2 - Group 2  Yenisey 2          Lokomotiv-Kazanka                 2.61         3.51         2.32                    1.45                    1.73              0.66                       1                  0.56                           0                  0.11                           0              0.62                       1              0.33                       0              0.76                       1              0.24                       0  2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391             nan                   nan             nan                   nan               nan                     nan                     3.18                          0.28   2.08   1.23  2021-08-06 06:00:00             2             1  O 1.5        Away                Home                  3                   1  No Match        Match
      1  2021-08-06 07:00:00  Russia     Youth League     Ural U19           Krylya Sovetov Samara U19         2.1          3.68         2.98                    1.25                    1.33              0.44                       0                  0.4                            0                  0.04                           0              0.56                       1              0.47                       0              0.6                        1              0.35                       0  2021-08-07 00:04:36.326391             nan                   nan             nan                   nan               nan                     nan                     2.58                          0.08   2.46   2.46  2021-08-06 07:00:00             1             1  N            Away                Draw                  2                   0  No Match        No Sel.
```

It displays fine here on SO however in my python environment (Pycharm) its not expanded.

I am using options provided in [pd.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) however it does not seem to work

I try:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 300)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10)
```

I get

```
 match_datetime  \
index                        
0      2021-08-06 06:00:00   
1      2021-08-06 07:00:00   
2      2021-08-06 08:00:00   
3      2021-08-06 08:30:00   
4      2021-08-06 08:30:00   

      country  \
index           
0      Russia   
1      Russia   
2       World   
3       China   
4       China   

                league  \
index                    
0      FNL 2 - Group 2   
1         Youth League   
2        Club Friendly   
3           Jia League   
4         Super League   
.....
```

However its not helping.

What would be the best way to print and display it like a normal dataframe?

Comment: Keep in mind that `display.width` is expressed in characters. You're telling Pandas that your terminal is only ten characters wide.

Comment: So I changed it to `pd.set_option('display.width', 300000)` and still the same thing

Comment: Hi, what happens when you increase "display_max_columns" to 100, for instance?

Comment: I have edited the question to include your try